# apolo graphql useLazyQuery transform data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have a file called `api-hooks` where I have a function..

I am using `@apollo/client`'s `useLazyQuery`.

```
export function useLazyProposalList() {
  const [getQueueData, { loading, data, error, fetchMore }] = useLazyQuery(PROPOSAL_LIST, {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  });

  const proposalList = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) {
      return null;
    }
    return transformProposals(data);
  }, [data]);

  return {
    getQueueData,
    fetchMore,
    loading,
    data: proposalList,
    error,
  };
}
```

And In my component, I use it like this:

```
const { getQueueData, data: queueData, fetchMore: fetchMoreProposals } = useLazyProposalList();
```

Now, if user clicks `load more` button, I call `fetchMoreProposals` function that was returned as `fetchMore` from `useLazyQuery`.

Now, the problem is that when calling this, I again have to call `transformProposals` in my COMPONENT for the returned data, which kind of annoys me. It would be much better to only have `transformProposals` only in `useLazyProposalList` .. Is this possible or there's no way of doing this ?

one way of doing this is the following:

```
export function useLazyProposalList() {
  const [getQueueData, { loading, data, error, fetchMore }] = useLazyQuery(PROPOSAL_LIST, {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  });

  const fetchMoreProposals = React.useCallback(
    async (options) => {
      if (fetchMore) {
        const { data, loading, error } = await fetchMore(options);
        return {
          data: transformProposals(data),
          loading,
          error,
        };
      }
      return {
        data: {},
      };
    },
    [fetchMore],
  );

  const proposalList = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) {
      return null;
    }
    return transformProposals(data);
  }, [data]);

  return {
    getQueueData,
    fetchMore: fetchMoreProposals,
    loading,
    data: proposalList,
    error,
  };
}
```

but I don't like this.

Comment: "*I again have to call `transformProposals` in my component*" - where? Can you show us that code please? And why do you think you need to call it again, doesn't your component use the `queueData` that the hook returns?

Comment: I have a pagination. So there's a `load more` button in the component and when you click on that, I call `fetchMoreProposals` function which again returns new data(which needs to be transformed again)

Comment: I think of abusing, too ... I guess you're using `fetchMore` return value while it is not the right thing ... use `network-only`, not `no-cache`

Comment: I don't understand how this `no-cache` or `network-only` makes a difference. I updated my question and included one way of doing this..

Comment: just call `fetchMore()`, don't use return value! - `data` will be updated ... and transformed ... it can contain only new data but it's explained in docs how to merge it

Comment: @NikaKurashvili Oops, I didn't realise you were talking about `fetchMore` instead of `getQueueData`. But yes, wrapping it in a `fetchMoreProposals` function in your hook would be the way to go.

Comment: @xadm I don't understand what you mean. if I call `fetchMore` directly without using its return value,  how will it know to `transform` my data per my function ?

Comment: it will be called [by memo] in the hook over updated `data` (memo dependency)

Comment: it's not getting called. @xadm

Comment: I think `fetchMore` doesn't update the old data, it returns new data.

Comment: it will be called (by main `data` update) with `updateQuery` (or newer field policy merge) defined - see https://yvonnickfrin.dev/create-an-infinite-loading-list-with-react-and-graphql - example with hook and some 'data transform' (at return)